# Checking a string contains multiple pieces of text

Tags: php, while-loop, strpos

I'm developing a news site, and am allowing the authors of any articles to decide how many images they'd like to add within the article.

To include the image they need to input [image1] within the body of the article content, which is then converted into the image src on another page.

I'm attempting to write a piece of code that checks how many images the user has input, along with accompanying captions, then see if they have applied the [image#] and [caption#] tags for each.

**Desired functionality:**

If the user has chosen to upload two images for the article, they must also insert two captions. They must then state [image1][caption1] and [image2][caption2] wherever they desire within the article's content.

If the user has posted the images and the captions into the form, however have not included the correct number of [image#] and [caption#], I'm looking to prompt them into doing so using `strpos()`. However am struggling to achieve this.

Here is my code thus far, if anyone could show me what I'm doing wrong it'd be appreciated.

Cheers, Rich

```
$z = 1;
while($z < $caption){
if (strpos($articleContent,'[caption$z]') == !false) {
echo 'You have added all of your caption tags in the article.';
$z++;
} else {
echo "You have not added all of your [caption#] tags in the article content.";
exit(); 
}
}
```

I'm then looking to simply C&P the same to count the [image#] tags.

Comment: Need to use double quotes. The `$z` is literal. Also it is `!==`, not `== !`. http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php Additionally is `$caption` an integer?

Comment: @chris85 is right. You might want to switch the if to check `!strpos` and move printing the success message to after the loop.

Comment: No, caption is a $_POST of text, I've corrected the !== and am still having no luck. What do you mean by $z being literal? If I'm looping through and adding $z++ shouldn't it be checking for everything until $z hits the number of $caption's?

Comment: I've just tried adding the if statement after the loop, no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a week of trying to solve this, I think I'd best share the answer as there seems to be a lack of people attempting to do the same.

**Solution:**

```
$articleContent = $_POST['articleContent'];
$imgCount = count($imgTmp1); // Count files array
$capCount = count($captions); // Count captions array 
$r = 0;
$c = 0;

while($r < $imgCount){

$i = 1;
$z = 1;
$r++;
$c++;

$value = "[image$r]";
for($check = strpos($articleContent,$value);$i<$imgCount;$i++){
}
if($check !== false){
// Your success, if any
} else {
echo "<span class='error'>You need to include '$value' into the article content.</span>";
exit();
}

$value2 = "[caption$c]";
for($check2 = strpos($articleContent,$value2);$z<$capCount;$z++){
}

if($check2 !== false){
// Your success, if any
} else {
echo "<span class='error'>You need to include '$value2' into the article content.</span>";
exit();
}
}
```

The issue wasn't with the variables themselves, as they were echoing out correctly in every loop I attempted the check with. The issue was actually with the `strpos`. As you can see, I've inserted the `strpos` within the loop itself and it works like a peach.

Good luck to anyone else struggling with the same issue I have here, thanks to everyone else for their help too.

Answer (score 2):

Try [preg_match_all()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)

If it's expected to always be a sequential string (like [image1][caption1]) you can try it like this:

```
<?php

$articleContent = 'The M-209 is a portable, mechanical cipher machine.
[image1][caption1] In this photograph, an intermediate gear unit meshes 
with gears adjoining each key wheel. 
[image2][caption2]Visible to the  left of the image is the typewheel 
that prints out messages and ciphertext onto paper tape.';

// Is something out of place or any captions missing?
preg_match_all( '~(\[image([\d])+\](?!\s*\[caption\\2\]))~i', $articleContent, $matches );

empty( $matches[0] ) or die( 'Please add proper caption to: ' . implode( ', ', $matches[0] ). '.' );

?>
```

And if there's supposed to be a bunch of things between the two respective tags, (like [image1] blah 123 yeah [caption1]) use this regex instead:

```
<?php

preg_match_all( '~(\[image([\d]+)\](?!.*\[caption\\2\]))~i', $articleContent, $matches );

?>
```

---

And here's a different approach without the missing caption number report...

```
<?php

$articleContent = 'The M-209 is a portable, mechanical cipher 
machine used primarily by the US military in World War II, though 
it remained in active use through the Korean War. 
[image1][caption1] In this photograph, an intermediate gear unit 
meshes with gears adjoining each key wheel. 
[image2][caption2] Visible to the left of the image is the typewheel 
that prints out messages and ciphertext onto paper tape.';

preg_match_all( '~(\[image[0-9]+\])~i', $articleContent, $images_array );

if( !empty( $images_array[0] ) ) {

    preg_match_all( '~(\[caption[0-9]+\])~i', $articleContent, $captions_array );

    if( count( array_unique( $images_array[0] ) ) > count( array_unique( $captions_array[0] ) ) ) {

        echo 'You have not added all of your [caption#] tags in the article content.';
        exit;


    } else {

        echo 'You have added all of your caption tags in the article.';

    }

}

?>
```

Comment: Nice.  Could this handle them mismatching caption and image #? (Really more of an exercise for the OP)

Comment: With a few more checks, it surely can.

Answer (score 2):

This might be overkill, but hopefully it gives you something useful.

```
<?php

$article_content = "abc[image1]def[image2]ghi[image5]jkl[image123]mno" .
    "[imagex]pqr[image3stu[image10]vwximage4]yza[caption3]bcd[caption1]" .
    "efg[caption2]hij[caption5]klm[caption123]nop[caption10]qrs[image100]";


function find_tags($content, $tag_name) {
    $tag_length = strlen($tag_name);
    $ids = [];
    $position = 0;
    while(($position = strpos($content, "[" . $tag_name, $position)) !== false) {
        $end_position = strpos($content, "]", $position);
        if(is_numeric($id = substr($content, $position + $tag_length + 1, $end_position - $position - $tag_length - 1))) {
            $ids[] = $id;
        }
        $position++;
    }
    return $ids;
}

function match_ids($tag_ids) {

    $tag_names = array_keys($tag_ids);

    sort($tag_ids[$tag_names[0]]);
    sort($tag_ids[$tag_names[1]]);

    $missing_ids_in_0 = array_diff(
        $tag_ids[$tag_names[1]],
        $tag_ids[$tag_names[0]]
    );
    $missing_ids_in_1 = array_diff(
        $tag_ids[$tag_names[0]],
        $tag_ids[$tag_names[1]]
    );
    return array(
        $tag_names[0] . "_missing" => $missing_ids_in_0,
        $tag_names[1] . "_missing" => $missing_ids_in_1
    );
}

$tag_ids = array(
    "image" => find_tags($article_content, "image"),
    "caption" => find_tags($article_content, "caption")
);
var_dump($tag_ids);

$match_result = match_ids($tag_ids);
var_dump($match_result);
echo "<br>";

if(sizeof($match_result["image_missing"])) {
    foreach($match_result["image_missing"] as $id) {
        echo "Please add an [image" . $id . "] tag.<br>"; 
    }
}
if(sizeof($match_result["caption_missing"])) {
    foreach($match_result["caption_missing"] as $id) {
        echo "Please add a [caption" . $id . "] tag.<br>"; 
    }
}

?>
```

Output:

```
array (size=2)
  'image' => 
    array (size=6)
      0 => string '1' (length=1)
      1 => string '2' (length=1)
      2 => string '5' (length=1)
      3 => string '123' (length=3)
      4 => string '10' (length=2)
      5 => string '100' (length=3)
  'caption' => 
    array (size=6)
      0 => string '3' (length=1)
      1 => string '1' (length=1)
      2 => string '2' (length=1)
      3 => string '5' (length=1)
      4 => string '123' (length=3)
      5 => string '10' (length=2)
array (size=2)
  'image_missing' => 
    array (size=1)
      2 => string '3' (length=1)
  'caption_missing' => 
    array (size=1)
      4 => string '100' (length=3)

Please add an [image3] tag.
Please add a [caption100] tag.
```

Comment: That's pretty slick. If you use @bornkillaz `preg_match_all` slightly modified `preg_match_all( '~\[' . $tag_name . '([0-9]+)\]~i', $content, $ids);` you can just `return $ids[1];` in `find_tags`. Also, i'm pretty sure the `sort`s aren't necessary. +1

Comment: When I get to a computer later today I'll have a read through all of the answers. Thanks guys.

Comment: This did work however it matches the number of [caption] tags with [image] tags. The functionality is that when the user inserts a file upload field, they must input an [image1] and [caption1]. If they completely forget to input them both then the script wont know where to put the image of caption if they never exited. I've given you a +1 anyway man, thank you.

Comment: You're just trying to find all of the `[captionX]` tags that correspond to the indices given to images that have been uploaded? The last line in your original question made me think that you wanted to make sure each `[captionX]` tag had a corresponding `[imageX]` tag, and vice versa. I actually should have asked for clarification before writing such an involved solution.

Comment: Solved it at last. Thank you both for your help again. :)